# adding php class to server

Tags: php, multithreading

I developed a website using XAMPP local host, and I used a class that extends Thread interface, and everything was working fine.

But after I host my website using host monster, the PHP page didn't work, and when I checked if thread class or interface are exist using `class_exists()` and `interface_exists()` I got false for both, so I think that is my problem.

Is there any way to upload this class to the server or to my PHP files to be used?

note: to make Thread class works on XAMPP I needed to add some PHP classes like pthread. so I'm wondering if I have to add them again to the PHP files in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your host does not have the pthreads extension loaded.

Comment: this is what I've thought also, could you tell me how can I upload it to the server?